# having problems with simulating gravity in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm having problems with my gravity in my canvas.

The code I provided below. I tried to calculate the position in different ways, expected it to fall like usual with acceleration, except it just floats in the air.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var m = canvas.getContext('2d');
var gravity = 9.8; //as in 9.8m/s²
var height = 0;
var v = Math.sqrt((2 * height) / gravity);

function update() {
  m.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  m.fillRect(0, height, 10, 10);
  height += v;
  return v;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning `v` stops the function from requesting the next animation frame. Also, the values of `height` and `v` always remain zero.

I assigned `height` an initial value greater than zero, declared `v` within the function, and removed the `return`.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const m = canvas.getContext('2d');
const gravity = 9.8; //as in 9.8m/s²
let height = 1;

function update() {
  m.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  m.fillRect(0, height, 10, 10);
  let v = Math.sqrt((2 * height) / gravity);
  height += v;
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: so it's just the variable problems lmao  thanks btw

Comment: @Zai: no, it is not "just a variable problem". You need basic understanding of how functions work and what it means to return from a function. These concepts are JavaScript (and programming) at their most basic.